# Html DOM Object not listing properties?

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to pull text from a web page with the below code:

```
const theHtml = document.children[0];
function showThePage(htmlObject){
  for(var key in htmlObject){
    console.log(key);
    console.log(htmlObject.hasOwnProperty(key));
    if(htmlObject.hasOwnProperty(key))
    {
      if(htmlObject.key.hasOwnProperty('textContent')){
        console.log(key.textContent);
      }
    }
  }
}
showThePage(theHtml);
```

Something screwy is going on with the properties/children. When I check for the property by the name of each key, it is never true (execution *never* enters the if statement)... meaning the htmlObject has no properties by the name of the given keys. However, when I examine the DOM/DevTools, the properties are in fact listed on the HtmlObject. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use square brackets to access the property on the htmlObject that is equal to the value of `key`

```
if(htmlObject[key].hasOwnProperty('textContent')){
 // ...
}
```

In your case, you're looking to check weather the *value* of `key` is in the `htmlObject` The string literal `"key"` is perhaps equivalent to key in the case of dot notation vs [] notation.

Comment: unfortunately, this did not work as textContent is not an "own" property of the node apparently, but instead it is a property of the prototype.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `document.querySelectorAll()` .. you can use any jQuery/CSS selector to return only the elements you want to pull text from.

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('*');
for ( var i = 0 ; i < elements.length ; ++i ) {
    var key = elements[i];
    if ( key && key.textContent ) {
        console.log(key,key.textContent);
    }
}
```